# Using computed value for sub key with React setState

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I would like to be able to use computed values for *sub keys* when updating state in React.

I understand how to use computed values in straightforward settings like this:

```
this.setState({ [name]: value });
```

But I am having trouble getting key-value computation to work for a situation like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        foo: { a: 1, b: 2 }
    }; 
}

const keyToChange = 'a';
const value = 3;

this.setState({ foo[keyToChange]: value });
```

How can I make something that works like

```
this.setState({ foo.a: value });
```

But **where `a` can be a computed value**?

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
const subKeyName = 'a';

// Doesn't work
const nameOfKey = 'foo.' + subKeyName;
this.setState({ [`${nameOfKey}`]: value });

// Doesn't work
this.setState({ foo[subKeyName]: value });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the old properties in foo:

```
this.setState({ 
  foo: {
    [keyToChange]: value 
  }
});
```

If you want to keep old properties in foo but just add (or replace) one key in it:

```
this.setState(oldState => {
  return {
    foo: {
      ...oldState.foo,
      [keyToChange]: value
    }
  }
});
```

That last example is using object spread syntax, which is not yet a standardized part of javascript (currently a [stage 4 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), so it will be part of the language soon). So you should be using [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html) if you want to use it at this time. If you don't have that plugin, the equivalent with standard javascript is:

```
this.setState(oldState => {
  return {
    foo: Object.assign({}, oldState.foo, {[keyToChange]: value})
  }
});
```